# Derivation of second-order derivative of harmonic potential well

Tags: potential, harmonic-oscillator, polymers

For a harmonic potential well:

\begin{equation}
U(r)=\frac{1}{2}(r-R) \cdot K(r) \cdot(r-R)
\end{equation}

where $R$ is a $3N$ dimensional vector describing the stable conformation of $N$ atoms, and $r$ a $3N$ dimensional vector describing the same atoms in its current conformation. This can also be re-written as:

\begin{equation}
U=\frac{1}{2} k\left(\left\|r_{i}-r_{j}\right\|-\left\|R_{i}-R_{j}\right\|\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{2} k(s_{ij}-s^{o}_{ij})^{2}
\end{equation}

To note,
\begin{equation}
r_{i j}^{2}=\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)^{2}+\left(y_{i}-y_{j}\right)^{2}+\left(z_{i}-z_{j}\right)^{2}
\end{equation} so it follows that

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial r_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)}{r_{i j}}
\end{equation}

I am trying to understand the derivation of the Hessian matrix \begin{equation}
K_{i j}=\frac{\partial^{2} U}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}
\end{equation}

What I can't seem to understand is why:

(1) \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2} U_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}=\frac{k}{s_{i j}^{2}}\left(x_{j}-x_{i}\right)^{2}
\end{equation}
(2) \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2} U_{i j}}{\partial x_{i} \partial y_{j}}=\frac{-k}{s_{i j}^{2}}\left(x_{j}-x_{i}\right)\left(y_{j}-y_{i}\right)
\end{equation}

Why do the second partial derivatives change signs w.r.t. different spatial axis? No matter how I try to find this derivative, I cannot seem to get the $\frac{k}{s_{ij}^{2}}$ factor.

Comment: Are you taking $K$ to be a uniform $k$, or to vary with $r$?

Comment: I'm taking $K$ to vary with $r$ ($K(r)$)

source - https://web.archive.org/web/20200927012331/https://bougui505.github.io/science/2014/11/02/elastic-network-model-of-proteins-with-python.html

Comment: The abbreviation $\rho:=r-R$ obtains $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho_i}$ and $U=\frac12\rho_lK_{lm}\rho_m$ in Einstein notation so (long equation in next comment) This is much more complicated than $K_{ij}$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}&=\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial\rho_i\partial\rho_j}\\&=\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}\left(K_{jm}\rho_m+\rho_l\frac{\partial K_{lm}}{\partial r_j}\rho_m+\rho_lK_{lj}\right)\\&=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial K_{jm}}{\partial r_i}\rho_m+K_{ji}+\frac{\partial K_{im}}{\partial r_j}\rho_m+\rho_l\frac{\partial^2K_{lm}}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}\rho_m+\rho_l\frac{\partial K_{lj}}{\partial r_j}+K_{ij}+\rho_l\frac{\partial K_{lj}}{\partial r_i}\right).\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry, $\frac{\partial K_{lj}}{\partial r_j}$ should read $\frac{\partial K_{lj}}{\partial r_i}$.

Comment: If $$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{k}{s_{ij}}_{x}\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)
$$ , then why isn't the second derivative just a constant $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_{i}}\right)=\frac{\partial^{2} U}{\partial x_{j} \partial x_{i}}=\frac{-k}{s_{ij}}
$$

Comment: That requires some constraints on $K_{ij}$.

Comment: I guess my main confusion largely comes from expanding the partial derivative through chain rule. If $$
\frac{\partial U_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{\partial U_{i j}}{\partial r_{i j}} \frac{\partial r_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}}
$$ then $$
\frac{\partial^{2} U_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}{ }^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2} U_{i j}}{\partial r_{i j} \partial x_{i}} \frac{\partial r_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}}+\frac{\partial U_{i j}}{\partial r_{v j}} \frac{\partial^{2} r_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}{ }^{2}}
$$

Comment: What I can't seem to shake off is the second term in the expanded derivative. I can see the resemblance of the first term but what about the second RHS term? Am I evaluating this derivative correctly?

$$
=k_{i j} \frac{\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)^{2}}{r_{i j}{ }^{2}}+k_{i j} r_{i j} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\left(\frac{x_{i}-x_{i}}{r_{i j}}\right)
$$

Comment: Re: your penultimate comment: surely you mean$$\frac{\partial U_{ij}}{\partial x_k}=\frac{\partial U_{ij}}{\partial r_{lm}}\frac{\partial r_{lm}}{\partial x_k}.$$